# Databricks connection type not showing in Airflow

Tags: airflow

Databricks connection type not showing in Airflow.
I have installed airflow using docker and also installed the airflow package:"apache-airflow-providers-databricks".

After restarting the webserver also, Databricks connector is not showing.
Can anybody help me in resolving the same?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LrOzh.png)

Comment: Where did you installed the databricks provider ? Make sure it is installed in the workers containers. While containers are started enter the bash and check if the library is installed by running pip freeze | grep "apache-airflow-providers-databricks".

Answer (score 0):

I installed the databricks provider in the worker container and got the same problem. After a while a noticed it was also not listing in **Main > Providers** of the airflow web application, so I tried installing it in the webserver container as well, and that solved the problem. Restarting docker containers was necessary. Bellow are the commands I used:

```
docker exec -ti -u airflow <<worker_container_name>> pip install apache-airflow-providers-databricks
docker exec -ti -u airflow <<webserver_container_name>> pip install apache-airflow-providers-databricks
docker-compose stop
docker-compose start
```